# How do I use \raisebox with \enumerate on Texlive 2014?

Tags: enumerate

I have this weird problem where the same code complies fine on one computer, which has Texlive 2013, and on a computer running Texlive 2014 it doesn't compile. Both computers are using Luatex on Ubuntu 14.10.

The purpose of the code is to adjust vertical spacing in numerical list items. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\raisebox{0.5em}{\arabic*}}
\usepackage{realscripts}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Here is an item.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

To repeat, this runs fine on texlive 2013. On texlive 2014 it generates the following error:

```
! Use of \\enumerate doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                              #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.7 \item
    Here is an item.
```

Note that the use of `\realscripts` here is important for reasons I don't understand. It was originally included in the book I am working on. But when I tried to remove everything to identify this problem, I found that removing it generated the same error as above, even on texlive 2013.

The original code used the deprecated form `\setenumerate`, which produced the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to `\protect` `\raisebox`. (At least you need to do that until the 2015 latex release: in the test builds of the next latex release the original document works without error)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\protect\raisebox{0.5em}{\arabic*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Here is an item.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

---

The fact that it did not cause an error in 2013 and will not in 2015 but did in 2014 are all related.  `\resizebox` was (or is) a fragile command so needs `\protect` however the `fixltx2e` package distributed with latex fixed various things including making `\raisebox` robust so that it did not need `\protect`. from 2015 onwards `fixltx2e` is not needed and the improvements are enabled by default, older versions of `fontspec` (which is included by `realscripts`) used to load `fixltx2e` but `fontspec` stopped doing that to avoid side issues (like this:-) unrelated to font selection. (Thanks to @cfr for supplying me a 2013 trace to compare)

Comment: It's nothing to do with `realscripts` or `enumitem`, right? I have identical copies of the packages for 2013 and 2014 yet it compiles in the one case but not the other....

Comment: @cfr something's changed, enumitem I would guess, but I don't have tl213 to hand. If you add \tracingall and run it in 2013 and email me the log I'll see what's changed `\raisebox` hasn't changed since 1995 (until it was made robust in the 2015 pre-release)

Comment: It is expected to take a long time?

Comment: @cfr if I put `\tracingall` just before `\begin{enumerate}` I get `$ time pdflatex ff607 > /dev/null

real    0m1.053s
user    0m0.968s
sys     0m0.078s
` so a second or so

Comment: Well you didn't say ***where*** to put it! OK. Let me try that. I can't email you a 75M file anyhow....

Comment: You are the first person who has ever managed to crash Thunderbird just by trying to put their email address in :),

Comment: @cfr updated with analysis of your trace thanks.

Comment: Can't upvote again so you'll have to make do with a comment ;).